# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in) FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, google-authentication

I have run flutter doctor and it is reporting no error. The google authentication works fine in IOS but not for android. People tend to say an update does the job but it has not worked for me.It crashes on: _currentUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

```
    try {
        _currentUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await _currentUser.authentication;

        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );
        final authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final user = await _auth.currentUser();
    }catch(ex){}
```

The pubspec file is as follows:

```
      name: app
      description: A new Flutter project.

      publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to                     
      pub.dev

      version: 1.0.0+1

      environment:
        sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

      dependencies:
        flutter:
          sdk: flutter

        cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
        modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
        http: ^0.12.2
        shared_preferences: ^0.5.8


        firebase_core: ^0.4.5
        firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
        cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
        flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
        flutter_facebook_auth: ^0.2.3
        google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
        flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0





      dev_dependencies:
        flutter_test:
          sdk: flutter


      flutter:

        uses-material-design: true

        assets:
           - assets/images/
        fonts:
        - family: Questrial
          fonts:
          - asset: assets/fonts/Questrial-Regular.ttf
            weight: 900
```

Comment: please share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: The post has been edited

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in one of two ways, I moved from master to stable branch and also completed the Facebook authentication. For whatever reason there is some dependency if you use the SignInButtons package so both needed to be implemented.